# CRC-16 specific example for serial connection

Tags: crc, crc16

While working with the following [PDF](https://www.emerson.com/documents/automation/roc-protocol-specifications-manual-for-fbx-series-en-455518.pdf), there is an example in

> Section 4: CRC-16 Code and Example

(page 95 or 91) that shows a serial packet with a CRC16 value of `133 (LSB)` and `24 (MSB)`.

However, I have tried different calculators, for example:

1. [Lammert](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation)
2. [Elaborate calculator](https://leventozturk.com/engineering/crc/)
3. [CRC calc](https://crccalc.com/)

but I cannot get the CRC16 values that the PDF indicates, regardless of the byte combination I use.

How can I correctly calculate the CRC16 in the example, preferably using one of these calculators? (otherwise, C/C++ code should work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular CRC is [CRC-16/ARC](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-arc). [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) generates the code for this CRC, which includes this simple bit-wise routine:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t crc16arc_bit(uint16_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001 : crc >> 1;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

The standard interface is to do `crc = crc16arc_bit(0, NULL, 0);` to get the initial value (zero in this case), and then `crc = crc16arc_bit(crc, data, len);` with successive portions of the message to compute the CRC.

If you do that on the nine-byte message in the appendix, `{1, 2, 1, 0, 17, 3, 'M', 'O', 'C'}`, the returned CRC is `0x1885`, which has the least significant byte `133` in decimal and most significant byte `24` in decimal.

Faster table-driven routines are also generated by crcany.

If you give `01 02 01 00 11 03 4d 4f 43` as hex to Lammert Bies' calculator, the very first one, called "CRC-16" gives `0x1885`.

If you give `0102010011034d4f43` to crccalc.com and hit Calc-CRC16, the second line is CRC-16/ARC, with the result `0x1885`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; it is exactly what I was missing!